# 404 Not Found in AJAX post call

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

I'm using Spring MVC and when I do an ajax post call I get a 404. My controller looks like this:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/mensaje")
public class MensajeController {

    public MensajeController() {
        super();
    }

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/prueba", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String prueba(@RequestParam("cuerpo") final String cuerpo) {
        String b = null;

        String a = null;

        return b;
    }
}
```

And the ajax call like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function() {      
        $("#save").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var myEditor = document.querySelector('#editor');
            var html = myEditor.children[0].innerHTML;

            $.ajax({
                    type : "POST",
                    url : "/Gestion-Practicas/mensaje/prueba",
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    data: {'cuerpo': html},
                    async: false,
                    cache: false,
                    delay: 15,
                    success: function(data){
                        alert('success');
                    },
                    error: function (xhr) {
                        alert(xhr.responseText);
                    }
                });     
        });

    });
</script>
```

The url from where I do the ajax call is:

```
http://localhost:8080/Gestion-Practicas/mensaje/create.do
```

The url who appears in the Chrome's console after doing the ajax call is:

```
http://localhost:8080/Gestion-Practicas/mensaje/prueba
```

Summarizing, the ajax call never reaches the controller's method and I don't know why

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `@RequestParam` use `@RequestBody`

`@RequestParam` - It's used for query parameters in request url.

`@RequestBody` - It's a post body payload.

Convert your `String cuerpo` to a class with property `String cuerpo`

```
public class PostBody{
  private String cuerpo;
  public String getCuerpo(){
    return this.cuerpo;
   }

   public void setCuerpo(String cuerpo){
     this.cuerpo = cuerpo;
   }
}
```

Now your line `public String prueba(@RequestParam("cuerpo") final String cuerpo)`

Updated will look like `public String prueba(@RequestBody final PostBody postBody)`.

Comment: What's the point of doing this? Would I have to create a different class for each object I wanted to send through ajax? I tried but it didn't work anyway, since the problem is that the method of the controller isn't being reached

Comment: Just looking at the controller code it's seems to look okay. Which version of spring you are using.

Comment: I'm using Spring 4.0.3

Comment: where did you configure `Gestion-Practicas` namespace. From controller it's looks like `/mensaje/prueba` the correct url.

Comment: `Gestion-Practicas` is the name of the project and it's configured to be added to the root of the url. I also tried `/mensaje/prueba` and `mensaje/prueba` but the result is the same

Comment: Name of the project doesn't need to be in url. Can you do one thing just for testing instead of POST make it GET and try to hit from browser tab.

Comment: I also tried with GET before but I got the same result as well